# Frontier node template fails to build

Tags: frontier, frontier-node-template, frontier-workshop

I've just checked out the latest frontier version from `master` branch (`28c4bce`). When I'm trying to run `./node-template-release.sh` I'm getting the following error. How to fix this?

```
Compiling pallet-grandpa v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=master#6001b59f)
  error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `Event`
     --> /tmp/.tmp9bl8nQ/template/runtime/src/lib.rs:286:1
      |
  286 | impl pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `Event` in implementation
      |
      = help: implement the missing item: `type Event = Type;`

  error[E0599]: no variant or associated item named `max_encoded_len` found for enum `pallet_ethereum::RawOrigin` in the current scope
     --> /tmp/.tmp9bl8nQ/template/runtime/src/lib.rs:391:1
      |
  391 | / construct_runtime!(
  392 | |     pub enum Runtime where
  393 | |         Block = Block,
  394 | |         NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
  ...   |
  409 | |     }
  410 | | );
      | |_^ variant or associated item not found in `pallet_ethereum::RawOrigin`
      |
      = note: this error originates in the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  Some errors have detailed explanations: E0046, E0599.
  For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0046`.
  error: could not compile `frontier-template-runtime` due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: Command::new(\"cargo\").args(&[\"build\",\n                                \"--all\"]).current_dir(path).status().expect(\"Compiles node\").success()', src/main.rs:188:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

**My environment:**

- `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`
- `rustc 1.61.0 (fe5b13d68 2022-05-18)`
- `rustc 1.63.0-nightly (bb8c2f411 2022-06-19)`

Comment: I figure for straight up bugs like this seems to be, filling an issue might be best? I suspect the template is out of date from master, it may be that you cleared the lock file? https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/6001b59f9f64a133d55fc13a495acc76eb4b532f is the latest commit at this time, and frontier assuredly is not up to date with this.

Comment: @DanShields So I did: https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/issues/737

Answer (score 0):

In the First one there is missing

```
Type Event = Event
```

and in the second , there is missing `MaxcodedLen` in the `Struct RawOrigin` in your code